# Why episodes of my podcast are not visible on iTunes?

Tags: itunes, rss, podcasts

I had created my podcasts's feed with Podcastgen and I've added the feed to iTunes. The episodes are not visible in iTunes:

[image]

the episodes are also not visible on iTunes webpage:
[image]

However, after I've subscribed to the podcast the episodes are visible in my library:
[image]

Any ideas, why the eopisodes are not visible in iTunes Store and on iTunes webpage?

Comment: I don't know for sure however I'm pretty sure that everything in the apple store requires a licence to put online. It's like that for apps, music, etc so I don't see why it wouldn't be the same for podcasts.